# Accessing the data withing a FormBuilder from the html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

so I initialized a FormBuilder in the onInit Lifecyle:

```
surveyForm: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.surveyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       'surveyTitle': new FormControl(null),
       'surveyDescription': new FormControl(null),
       'questionsDetail': this.formBuilder.array([
         this.formBuilder.group({
           'questionType': new FormControl('mcq'),
           'question': new FormControl(null),
           'choices': this.formBuilder.array([])
         })
       ])
     });
    };
```

I cant figure out how to access the controls of my FormArray

```
<form [formGroup]="surveyForm">
  <input formControlName = "surveyTitle">
  <textarea formControlName = "surveyQuestion"></textArea><div formArrayName='questionsDetail'>
    <div [FormArrayName]="questionsDetail">
      <div *ngFor="let questionDetail of surveyForm.get('questionsDetail').controls; let i=index">
        <div [FormGroup]="i">
          ...
          <div [FormArrayName]="choices">
            <div *ngFor="let choice of surveyForm.get('questionsDetail').controls.get('choices').controls; let in=index">
              <div [FormGroup]="in">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

so can anyone show me the syntax of getting the data inside FormGroup which is nested inside a FormArray. I cant seem to get the correct syntax for ngFor in accessing the formBuilder.

If you can help me, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```html
<form [formGroup]="surveyForm">
  <input formControlName = "surveyTitle">
  <textarea formControlName = "surveyQuestion"></textArea><div formArrayName='questionsDetail'>
    <div formArrayName="questionsDetail">
      <div *ngFor="let questionDetail of surveyForm.get('questionsDetail')['controls']; let i=index">
        <div [FormGroup]="i">
          ...
          <div formArrayName="choices">
            <div *ngFor="let choice of surveyForm.get('questionsDetail')['controls'][i].get('choices')['controls']; let in=index">
              <div [FormGroup]="in">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Note that I am not binding to `[FormArrayName]` in the line `[FormArrayName]="questionsDetail`. This should be `formArrayName="questionsDetail`. Same for `choices`

Comment: Oh thanks, but now i get an error at my *ngFor stating "Identifier 'controls' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain such a member"

Comment: That is now a typescript issue, I have updated the code to access the controls with the bracket notation `['controls']` rather than dot notation `.controls`

Comment: I get this error now "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'AbstractControl' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?" at <div *ngFor="let questionDetail of surveyForm.get('questionsDetail')['controls']; let i=index">

Comment: Yes, i did I used this code get questionsDetailcontrols() {
    return (this.surveyForm.get('questionsDetail') as FormArray);
  } and *ngFor="questionDetailcontrols.control". I think it has to know that its of type FormArray thats why we have to explicitly convert it in the .ts file.